# Multiple connections using multiple IP addresses to same PC

Tags: snmp, network-monitoring, windows

**Background:** I have a network management application (like Nagios or OpenNMS but not either one) under testing that requires all managed devices to have individual IP addresses ie. SNMP traps received from the devices are distinguished by the senders IP address.

**Task:** I'm trying to simulate a network of SNMP managed devices on a single Windows laptop. The simulator laptop is connected to the server running the network management application via a switch that, in turn, is connected to a gateway and to the internet. I do't have access to the devices beyond the switch.

**Problem:** I need to create "a large network" of SNMP connected devices. I am trying to do this by adding several IP address to my laptop, running a simulator listening to all the addresses and connecting to it from the server via all the different IP addresses (not sure this actually is the best way, other suggestions?).

**Question:** How to create several connections from one Windows PC to another using private (virtual) IP addresses for each connection? What is happening is the connections (ping etc.) seem to go through the gateway and to the internet thus not working!

Cheers and thanks for all the help!

Comment: Do you have routes for the private networks? If not they're probably just heading to the gateway..

Comment: Routes set on both PCs with 'route add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 <ownIP>' which works only if switch is disconnected from the gateway. Otherwise packets get lost somewhere in the void.

Comment: So, can you add in what IPs are configured on the laptop, and then on the server, and if there are firewalls in between or on the server or laptop?

Comment: Thanks @NickW, server has 10.33.126.1, laptop 10.33.126.20 (and .21 and .22 etc) and this works as long as switch is not connected on the internet. Firewalls are disabled, with firewall it doesn't even get this far. <ownIP> is the public IP I use to connect to internet.

Comment: Yeah, I think probably the packets might be getting lost on the way back. If you put the server and the laptop on a VLAN (set them up with an internet connected IP on a different VLAN) you will be able to exclude the route to the internet for them. Some OS's do not like getting packets destined for another address, 21 receiving 22 and so on.. are there other networks configured on the server or laptop?

Comment: My switch supports only port based VLANs. It's starting to seem I wont be able to reach elegant, SW only solution for this. I will need to get a dedicated client PC preferably with dual NICs. That way it's guaranteed to work. Thanks @NickW for your comments.